# PDF with Invisible Text inside a Text Box

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, acrobat-pro-dc

I have a PDF document, which contains several text boxes, but the text inside is invisible. I am able to select the text and copy/paste it into another document and see what is written inside the text box. However, I was wondering if there is a way to turn off this feature? I have looked into the font style, font size, font color, but no matter what changes I do the text still remains invisible. Would be really grateful if someone can help me out!

PS: The invisible text boxes are created by purpose, so it is not a bug in the software.

Comment: Try another reader, e.g. free Sumatra PDF (https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) or PDF-XChange Viewer (https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

It could probably mean an image or another object is upon your textboxes. This way the text is still selectable and can be copied, however, it is not visible. you need to remove that object from your pdf.